# PythonMagick Unable to open config file

Tags: windows-10, runtime-error, 64-bit, python-3.6, pythonmagick

I am running Python 3.6 in a venv on 64 bit Windows 10 inside PyCharm. Here are the steps I performed:

1. Open PyCharm and start a new project using Python 3.6 as the venv.
2. Downloaded the PythonMagick from a wheel file for Python3.6 from this source:[PythonMagick wheel file](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pythonmagick)
3. Open the terminal in PyCharm and run:
   `pip install PythonMagick-0.9.19-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`
4. Download ghostscript from here: [Ghostscript 9.25 for Windows (64 bit)](https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/download/gs925/gs925w64.exe) and run the exe file.
5. Add the ghostscript directory `C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.25\bin` to the user PATH environment variable.

Now I run the sample file from here

```
import PythonMagick
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pdf = 'a.pdf'
    p = PythonMagick.Image()
    p.read(pdf)
    p.write('doc.jpg')
```

I get the following error:

> RuntimeError: Magick: UnableToOpenConfigureFile `delegates.xml' @
>   warning/configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/714

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

When installing PythonMagick in a VENV, apparently you need to also add a system variable called MAGICK_HOME so that Magick can find the config files.

Add the following to the User Variable

`MAGICK_HOME = %your-project-dir%\venv\Lib\site-packages\PythonMagick`

Then restart PyCharm.